# working of "data-display" attribute

Tags: php, html

I have two radio buttons in my tab, one button for male and other for female. when any of the button is selected corresponding "data-title" value will display on another tab2. But when I select female, tab2 will shows 'male'.

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Applicant Gender<span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="controls">     
    <label class="radio">
        <input id="myRadio1"  type="radio" name="app_sex" value="M" data-title="Male"/>Male </label>
    <label class="radio">
        <input id="myRadio2"  type="radio" name="app_sex" value="F" data-title="Female">Female </label>
    <div id="app_sex_error"></div>  
</div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Applicant Sex:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <span id="appsex" class="text display-value" data-display="app_sex"></span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. You're not using PHP anywhere in the sample you show (this is just HTML). 2. You don't properly close the first `<div class="control-group">`.

Comment: provide code to fetch value of radio button

Answer (score -1):

I think you are using jquery so code should be like this

```
$('input[name=app_sex]:checked').val()
```